# How to debug TreeNodeCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, treeview, treenode

The code in question:

```
TreeNode categoryNode = categories.Nodes[category]; //BREAKPOINT HERE
categoryNode.Add("New Node")
```

My question is less about the code itself (it all makes sense to me), so much as the debugger.  When at the break point I want to look at the `TreeNode`s in `categories.Nodes`, but `categories.Nodes` is a `TreeNodeCollection` and I can't find the underlying list, array, or whatever is actually used under `TreeNodeCollection`'s hood.

How do I navigate the `TreeNodeCollection` so that I can find the actual list in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at individual nodes in the collection with categoryNode[0], changing the index.  Or drill down into the private *owner* property.  Its *children* field gives you a list of all the nodes.  Or if Linq is in scope, you can type

```
 categoryNode.OfType<TreeNode>(), results
```

Comment: Ok! Thanks.
For those who come here later:
the private owner property is a property of TreeNodeCollection, so in the example above it's categoryNode.Nodes.owner.children.
Both 'owner' and 'children' are private, so in the debugger are hiding in the "Private Variable" sections of their respective objects.